# How to create an infinite iterator to generate an incrementing alphabet pattern?

Tags: python, iterator, infinite

I've created a function that generates a list of alphabets incrementing continuously. A, B, C ..., Z. After Z, it goes to AA, AB, AC ...AZ. This pattern repeats. This is similar to MS Excel's column names. At the moment, this function generates a finite list of alphabets.

```
_column_name_generator() = ['A', 'B', ..., 'AA', 'AB', ..., 'BA', 'BB', ..., 'CV']
```

I can then iterate over it in conjunction with some finite list, e.g. 0-10. See my code below. What I'd like is to create a generator that will give me an infinitely long list of incrementing alphabets.

```
import string


def _column_name_generator():
    column_names = []
    for x in range(0, 100):
        if x < 26:
            column_names.append(string.ascii_uppercase[x % 26])
        else:
            column_names.append(column_names[x/26 - 1] + string.ascii_uppercase[x % 26])
    return column_names

container = []
for column_name, num in zip(_column_name_generator(), range(0, 10)):
    container.append(column_name + str(num))

print _column_name_generator()
print container

container = ['A0', 'B1', 'C2', 'D3', 'E4', 'F5', 'G6', 'H7', 'I8', 'J9']
```

Comment: explore about `yield`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yield `column_names`'s last element every time, and use `itertools.count` instead of `range` to provide infinite increase:

```
import itertools

def _column_name_generator():
    column_names = []
    for x in itertools.count():
        if x < 26:
            column_names.append(string.ascii_uppercase[x % 26])
        else:
            column_names.append(column_names[x/26 - 1] + string.ascii_uppercase[x % 26])
        yield column_names[-1]
```

---

A better solution, altering the original code but dismissing the need in a memory consuming list of `column_names`, would be

```
import itertools, string

def _column_name_generator():
    for i in itertools.count(1):
        for p in itertools.product(string.ascii_uppercase, repeat=i):
            yield ''.join(p)
```

it basically iterates over the product of length `i` the uppercase ascii letters (every sequence possible) when i is gradually increasing, starting from `1` (`A`, `B`, `C`).

Answer (score 1):

A less pythonic way

As implied in your question, one way is dividing by 26 converting the remainder into a letter at every step, until the division return 0. Use `%` (modulo) to get the remainder, `//` (floor division) to update the value for the next step. This could be the code:

```
numberOfElements = 100
letters = []
for counter in range(numberOfElements):
    i = counter
    newCharacter = i % 26
    i //= 26
    s = "" +chr(newCharacter + ord('A') )
    while i != 0:
        newCharacter = i % 26
        i //= 26
        s = chr(newCharacter + ord('A') ) + s
    letters.append(s)
print letters
```

Result:

> ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N',
>   'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'BA',
>   'BB', 'BC', 'BD', 'BE', 'BF', 'BG', 'BH', 'BI', 'BJ', 'BK', 'BL',
>   'BM', 'BN', 'BO', 'BP', 'BQ', 'BR', 'BS', 'BT', 'BU', 'BV', 'BW',
>   'BX', 'BY', 'BZ', 'CA', 'CB', 'CC', 'CD', 'CE', 'CF', 'CG', 'CH',
>   'CI', 'CJ', 'CK', 'CL', 'CM', 'CN', 'CO', 'CP', 'CQ', 'CR', 'CS',
>   'CT', 'CU', 'CV', 'CW', 'CX', 'CY', 'CZ', 'DA', 'DB', 'DC', 'DD',
>   'DE', 'DF', 'DG', 'DH', 'DI', 'DJ', 'DK', 'DL', 'DM', 'DN', 'DO',
>   'DP', 'DQ', 'DR', 'DS', 'DT', 'DU', 'DV']

Comment: A Python 3 version would be nice... :) Other things you might like to do: put it in a generator, allow the caller to specify upper or lower case, allow the caller to specify a starting point of the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution:

```
def compute_alphabet_array(nb_elements):
 alphabet_letters = [chr(i) for i in range(ord('A'),ord('Z') + 1)]
 nb_alphabet_letters_array = nb_elements/26
 letters = []
 last_alphabet_index = 0
 for i in range(0, int(nb_alphabet_letters_array)):
    last_alphabet_index = 0
    preceeding_letter = ""
    if (i > 0):
        last_alphabet_index = i - 1
        if (26 > i):
            preceeding_letter = alphabet_letters[last_alphabet_index]
        else:
            preceeding_letter = letters[26 + (i - 26)]
    current_alphabet_array = [preceeding_letter + alphabet_letters[j] for j in range(0, 26)]
    letters.extend(current_alphabet_array)

 # remaining 
 remaining_nb_alphabet_letters_array = nb_elements - (26 * int(nb_alphabet_letters_array))
 preceeding_letter = ""
 if (last_alphabet_index > 26):
    last_letter = letters[len(letters)-1]
    preceeding_letter = letters[letters.index(last_letter[:len(last_letter)-1]) + 1]
 else:
    preceeding_letter = alphabet_letters[last_alphabet_index + 1]

 remaining_alphabet_array = [ preceeding_letter +\
                            alphabet_letters[j] for j in range(0, remaining_nb_alphabet_letters_array)]
 letters.extend(remaining_alphabet_array)

 return letters
```

And then it can be used like this:

```
my_letters = compute_alphabet_array(26 * 1000 + 10)
```

displaying some last elements:

```
my_letters[len(my_letters)-11:]

>>> ['AMLZ','AMMA', 'AMMB', 'AMMC', 'AMMD', 'AMME', 'AMMF', 'AMMG', 'AMMH', 'AMMI','AMMJ']
```