# How to iterate through the alphabet?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

How can I iterate through the alphabet and have it continue past the letter Z? For example - a,b,c ... y,x,aa,ab,ac,ad

At the momenent this is my array

```
letters = [
           "a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","k",
           "l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u",
           "v","w","x","y","z", "aa", "ab", "ac", "ad", "ae",
           "af", "ag", "ah", "ai", "aj", "ak", "al", "am", "an",
           "ao", "ap", "aq", "ar", "as", "at", "au", "av","aw", "ax", "ay",
           "az", "ba", "bb", "bc", "bd", "be", "bf", "bg", "bh", "bi",
           "bj", "bk", "bl", "bm", "bn", "bo", "bp", "bq", "br", "bs", "bt",
           "bu", "bv","bw", "bx", "by", "bz","ca","cb","cc","cd","ce",
           "cf","cg","ch","ci","cj","ck","cl","cm","cn","co","cp",
           "cq","cr","cs","ct","cu","cv","cw"]
```

but I want to make it created within a loop.

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: This is the general algorithm, in C#: http://stackoverflow.com/a/182924/2436175. The key is dividing by 26 converting the remainder into a letter at every step, until the division return 0. Use `%` (modulo) to get the remainder, `//` (floor division) to update the value for the next step.

Comment: @Antonio I think you'll agree that Uriel's second itertools-based solution is a lot cleaner than messing around with modular arithmetic.

Comment: Do you really want them in a list? I think you'll find it much more convenient to have a generator that produces these strings for you.

Comment: @PM2Ring I agree. Since in the meantime I had the solution ready, I posted it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43918966/2436175). It shouldn't harm :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import string

letters = list(string.ascii_lowercase)

letters.extend([i+b for i in letters for b in letters])

print letters
```

By using a double for loop, we iterate over the alphabet like we normally would, except we can put the iteration in list comprehension, to save space and be more pythonic.

Comment: Instead of just code dumping why not explain what your program does? Right now it's not really a complete answer.

Comment: You are right. Please see my recent edit.

Comment: This assumes they want to stop at `zz`, a generic solution would be more useful, as suggested in the duplicate

Comment: Good point. However, I thought in the context of this problem and doing specifically what the OP had asked, this solution would suffice.

Answer (score 5):

since `string.ascii_lowercase` holds all of the lower-case letters, you can iterate through them in one loop (for 1-letter-string) or two (for 2-letters-string) and just add them to a list, like this:

```
import string
list = []
for c in string.ascii_lowercase: 
    list.append(c)

for c1 in string.ascii_lowercase:
    for c2 in string.ascii_lowercase:
        list.append(c1+c2)

print(list)
```

Comment: Instead of just code dumping why not explain what your program does? Right now it's not really a complete answer.

Answer (score 2):

`string` module would do the trick.

```
import string
alphabets=list(string.ascii_lowercase)
output=[] # output list
for a in alphabets:
     output.append(a)
for a in alphabets:
     for b in alphabets:
         output.append('%s%s' % (a,b))
print output
```