# pandas: set row values to letter of the alphabet corresponding to index number?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
   a    b   c    country
0  5    7   11   Morocco
1  5    9   9    Nigeria
2  6    2   13   Spain
```

I'd like to add a column `e` that is the letter of the alphabet corresponding to the index number, for example:

```
   a    b   c    country    e
0  5    7   11   Morocco    A
1  5    9   9    Nigeria    B
2  6    2   13   Spain      C
```

How can I do this? I've tried:

```
 df['e'] = chr(ord('a') + df.index.astype(int))
```

But I get:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Int64Index'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method would be to convert the index to a `Series` and then call `apply` and pass a `lambda`:

```
In[271]:
df['e'] = df.index.to_series().apply(lambda x: chr(ord('a') + x)).str.upper()
df

Out[271]: 
   a  b   c  country  e
0  5  7  11  Morocco  A
1  5  9   9  Nigeria  B
2  6  2  13    Spain  C
```

basically your error here is that `df.index` is of type `Int64Index` and the `chr` function doesn't understand how to operate with this so by calling `apply` on a `Series` we iterate row-wise to convert.

I think performance-wise a list comprehension will be faster:

```
In[273]:
df['e'] = [chr(ord('a') + x).upper() for x in df.index]
df

Out[273]: 
   a  b   c  country  e
0  5  7  11  Morocco  A
1  5  9   9  Nigeria  B
2  6  2  13    Spain  C
```

**Timings**

```
%timeit df.index.to_series().apply(lambda x: chr(ord('a') + x)).str.upper()
%timeit [chr(ord('a') + x).upper() for x in df.index]
1000 loops, best of 3: 491 µs per loop
100000 loops, best of 3: 19.2 µs per loop
```

Here the list comprehension method is significantly faster

Comment: How can we get the alphabet to restart after reaching letter Z? I have tried this approach, but after Z, it goes to some foreign characters ("|", ")" and even some Chinese (I think)). How can we get the letters to restart with AB, AC, AD after reaching Z?

Comment: @Rich see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42099312/how-to-create-an-infinite-iterator-to-generate-an-incrementing-alphabet-pattern

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative functional solution. Assumes you have less countries than letters.

```
from string import ascii_uppercase
from operator import itemgetter

df['e'] = itemgetter(*df.index)(ascii_uppercase)

print(df)

   a  b   c  country  e
0  5  7  11  Morocco  A
1  5  9   9  Nigeria  B
2  6  2  13    Spain  C
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `map` and get values from `df.index` as well:

`df['e'] = map(chr, ord('A') + df.index.values)`

If you do speed comparison:

```
# Edchum
%timeit df.index.to_series().apply(lambda x: chr(ord('A') + x))
10000 loops, best of 3: 135 µs per loop
%timeit [chr(ord('A') + x) for x in df.index]
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.38 µs per loop
# jpp
%timeit itemgetter(*df.index)(ascii_uppercase)
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.23 µs per loop
# Me
%timeit map(chr,ord('A') + df.index.values)
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.12 µs per loop
```

so `map` seems the faster but it might be because of the length of the data sample