# Python - how to map a column to a sequence of alphabetical letters?

Tags: python, string, pandas, mapping

I have a column in a data frame that I would like to map to a series of alphabetical letters.

Suppose I have the following 50 values in the column:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(50))
```

Now I would like to create a new column, where the number zero is mapped to A, 1 to B, etc. I have followed the method in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50860366/pandas-set-row-values-to-letter-of-the-alphabet-corresponding-to-index-number), however when the mapping reaches letter Z, it goes to some non-alphabetic characters. Here is the mapping code:

```
data['new column'] = [chr(ord('a') + x).upper() for x in data.index]
```

Observe that the number 26 and on were mapped to non-alphabetical characters. How can we create a mapping function such that the map will remap the number 26 to AA, 27 to AB, 28 to AC, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(50))

data["new column"] = [
    chr(ord('a') + x//26 - 1).upper() + chr(ord('a') + x%26).upper() if x >= 26
    else chr(ord('a') + x).upper()
    for x in data.index
]
```

Good luck

Comment: yep, well done. Note that this is Python3 code. For those still in (soon unsupported) Python2, change "x//26" into "x/26".

Comment: Thank you everyone, the generator solution also works. @Benoit Messiaen - this solution is more simple and is what I was looking for exactly.